# Proving the limit of the sequence for $\lim{a_nb_n} = ab$

Tags: real-analysis

the part of my proof that I am not sure is ok.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ Suppose $\lim{a_n}= a$ and $\lim{b_n}= b$. Since $\lim{a_n} = a, \exists N$ s.t. for $n>N$, $
|a_n-a|< \epsilon/2|b|$

and I will use the triangle inequality to complete an N epsilon proof. I just am not sure if it is ok to use $\epsilon/2|b|$ as by $n(\epsilon)$ . To me it does not seem well defined in this abstract proof.

Comment: Presumably $a_n \to a, b_n \to b$? You should ask a complete question.

Comment: you are correct, will add that assumption, so does this assumption allow me to  have b in denominator even if b=0?

Comment: No. If you do it this way, you need to split the proof into at least two parts.

Comment: you can't divide by 0, so if b=0 we can use b+1 instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what if b=0? and also is it given that a and b are the limits of $a_n$ and $b_n$.
then try to use the fact that converging sequences are bounded and $a_nb_n-ab=a_n(b_n-b)+b(a_n-a)$